# How to automatically determine the path of previous installation using Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to create a inno setup installer that patches a previous installation but i can't manage to force my installer determine the path where my previous installation is.
I tried using the `DefaultDirName={reg:HKxx\SubkeyName,ValueName|DefaultValue}` feature from inno but i'm not sure what to put in the DefaultValue's place.
How can i do that?

Edit:
i tried also this part:

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={code:GetPathInstalled}
[Code]
function GetPathInstalled (Param: String): String;
var
  Country: String;
begin
  RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\JoWooD\Painkiller Resurrection', 'Install', Country); 
end;
```

But when i run the installer the path is empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should look like:

```
[Code]
function GetPathInstalled (Param: String): String;
var
  Country: String;
begin
  RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'Software\JoWooD\Painkiller Resurrection', 'Install', Country); 
  Result:= Country;
end;
```

The return value from the RegQueryStringValue wasn't being returned as the result of the GetPathInstalled function.